# Jest cannot find module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, enzyme

Hi I am trying to use Jest, but it keeps giving an error of cannot find module. I am not sure if this has to do with the paths of the files. All the files below are located out of my src folder. I have my file set up below.

jest.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageDirectory": "coverage",
    "verbose": true,
    "roots": [
        "./__tests__"
    ],
    "transform": {
        "^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "coverageThreshold": {
        "global": {
            "branches": 78,
            "functions": 90,
            "lines": 90,
            "statements": 90
        }
    },
    "setupFiles": [
        "./setupTest"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules", "src"]
}
```

my test file located in __ test __:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Routes, { OrderScreen, ShippingScreen, HomeScreen } from ../../src/App';
import {
    MemoryRouter
} from 'react-router'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

let pathMap = {};
describe('App', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
        const component = shallow(<Routes />);
        pathMap = component.find(Route).reduce((pathMap, route) => {
            const routeProps = route.props();
            pathMap[routeProps.path] = routeProps.component;
            return pathMap;
        }, {});
        console.log(pathMap)
    })
    it('should show Home component for / router (getting array of routes)', () => {

        expect(pathMap['/']).toBe(HomeScreen);
    })
    it('should show News Feed component for /news router', () => {
        expect(pathMap['/order/:id']).toBe(OrderScreen);
    })
    it('should show News Feed component techdomain for /news router', () => {
        expect(pathMap['/shipping']).toBe(ShippingScreen);
    })
    it('should show No match component for route not defined', () => {
        expect(pathMap['/search/:keyword/page/:pageNumber']).toBe(HomeScreen);
    })

})
```

package jason

```
{
    "name": "frontend",
    "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.12.17",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
        "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
        "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.25.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
        "react-side-effect": "^2.1.1",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test:t": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "test": "jest",
        "test:cover": "jest --coverage",
        "open:coverage": "open ./coverage/lcov-report/index.html"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.13.8",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.8",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
        "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
        "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
        "jest": "^26.6.3",
        "jest-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
    }
}
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }],
        ['@babel/preset-react', { targets: { node: 'current' } }] // add this
    ]
};
```

Everything seems fine I've been following a tutorial but I cannot get over the error cannot find module it happens in my test file at this line

```
> 4 | import App, { App as AppComponent } from '../../src/App';
```

Does this have to do something with paths that need to be fixed? everything is located outside of my src folder. My main file App.js which I am trying to test is within my src folder.

Comment: Why do you have App imported twice? And have you created your app with Create-react-app command or the app template is created by your hand? It would be the best for you to share your code with codesandbox or via github repo

Comment: @StefanZivkovic I have been messing around with a project as well as following a tutorial. I can delete the duplicate but I still get an error about not finding react or the error moves up "import route"

Comment: it will be hard for people to help you when it is possible to always new errors show. Because of that the best for you is to share code so people can try it, see what the problems are and figure out what might be solution

Comment: Got it I will correct the file right now to what I currently have just to try and rule out any errors that I might already have such as what you pointed out right now.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
module.exports = {
  "collectCoverage": true,
  "coverageDirectory": "coverage",
  "verbose": true,
  "roots": ["<rootDir>/__tests__/"], // or "<rootDir>/src/__tests__/"
  "transform": {"^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest"},
  "coverageThreshold": {
    "global": {
      "branches": 78,
      "functions": 90,
      "lines": 90,
      "statements": 90
    }
  },
  "setupFiles": ["<rootDir>/setupTest"],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^src/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
  }
}
```

Comment: After trying that it gave me a new error. " Cannot find module 'react' from '../node_modules/react-side-effect/lib/index.js' " Not sure what this means. Both my react and react-dom are the same version.

Comment: try to remove the `roots` from `jest.config.js` file, since `testRegex` has `__tests__` by default it should pick you test files automatically. [Ref](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#testregex-string--arraystring)

Comment: If I move my test file into src folder it will start working but then fail again with the same react error. Could this be an issue with the test app file?